# How to Guarantee Equivalent Behavior of `await` from `ContinueWith` in both UI and Non-UI Code

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, async-await, ui-thread

I'm in search of the simplest and safest way to fully guarantee the same behavior as `await` but using `Task.ContinueWith`, most specifically to ensure that if the original caller is in the UI thread then the continuation occurs on the UI thread, otherwise it should continue on any thread. My current approach throws an exception in some cases which I can't see an obvious way to prevent in advance.

My prior understanding was that this code:

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
DoSomethingElse();
```

and this code:

```
DoSomethingAsync().ContinueWith(
     t => DoSomethingElse(),
     TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

ought to be equivalent, both resulting in `DoSomethingElse()` executing on the original calling thread if it was a UI thread, otherwise the continuation thread would be undefined.

However, it appears that `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` fails in at least some contexts when there is no UI thread or synchronizer defined. This occurs, at minimum, in Mono WASM projects. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext?view=net-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) also mentions the method can fail if "the current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler", but it doesn't say how to check whether this is the case before attempting to use it with `ContinueWith`.

As this code will be shared among many different consumers, from WPF to Mono WASM and others, I need a solution that fits all of them and doesn't require the consumer to specify if it's in a UI context or not.

What would be the simplest way to write the second block so that the continuation occurs on the UI thread when there is in fact a valid synchronization context such as in a WPF app - but also doesn't throw an exception if there isn't one - exactly the way `await` would?

Comment: Why do you want to use continue with in the first place?  It's rarely the best tool for the job, and it's always possible to implement whatever you would have done using it with `await` instead, so it's never *needed*.

Comment: @Servy if I call an `async void` method from the UI thread (for example inside a property setter), am I guaranteed that everything in that method after its own internal `await`s will still execute on the UI thread?

Comment: You're guaranteed that each await will capture the current synchronization context at the time of the `await` and use that to run the continuation after the await.  Most UI threads will have a synchronization context such that as long as you don't set the sync context to anything else your guarantee would hold true, but if you mess with the current sync context or the UI thread doesn't have a well behaved sync context, that wouldn't hold true.  So "probably, but if you actively tried, you could violate that guarantee".

Comment: @Tarazed They specifically asked about the behavior of an async method called from the UI thread, so what makes you think they're using `await` in a non-async method called from a non-UI thread?

Comment: @Servy yeah, but of course if I mess with the sync context I imagine that'll affect `await` too so I see your point. Still I would like to know how to use `ContinueWith` safely or at least know if the current synchronization context is safe to use with it. Chalk it up to academic curiousity if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't use `await`. Code using `await` is easier to write and maintain than code using the old `ContinueWith` method.

That said, there are a couple major differences. The first is that `await` captures the current context; this is `SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current` (or no context at all, which is logically equivalent to `TaskScheduler.Default`). `await` schedules its continuation directly on that context and doesn't wrap the `SynchronizationContext` into a `TaskScheduler`.

So, if you want to use `ContinueWith`, then you can use `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`, but there's already a semantic difference: with a non-`null` `SynchronizationContext.Current`, the `await` continuation would have `TaskScheduler.Current` equal to `TaskScheduler.Default`, whereas the `ContinueWith` continuation would have `TaskScheduler.Current` equal to a `TaskScheduler` instance wrapping that `SynchronizationContext`. Perhaps not a huge issue, but be aware that many low-level TPL methods implicitly use `TaskScheduler.Current` (including `ContinueWith`).

The other major difference is that `ContinueWith` doesn't have a built-in understanding of asynchronous code. So if `DoSomethingElse` is asynchronous, then the behavior will be different. In that case, `ContinueWith` would return a `Task<Task>` and you should call `Unwrap` to more closely emulate the behavior of `await`.

There's also a number of minor differences; passing `TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` should be closer to the `await` behavior. You could also try `TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler` which should cause `TaskScheduler.Current` to be `TaskScheduler.Default` in the continuation.

So in summary, these two should be *mostly* equivalent:

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
DoSomethingElseSynchronously();

var continuationTask = DoSomethingAsync()
    .ContinueWith(
        _ => DoSomethingElseSynchronously(),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler,
        SynchronizationContext.Current == null ? TaskScheduler.Default : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

or, if asynchronous:

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
await DoSomethingElseAsync();

var continuationTask = DoSomethingAsync()
    .ContinueWith(
        _ => DoSomethingElseAsync(),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler,
        SynchronizationContext.Current == null ? TaskScheduler.Default : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    .Unwrap();
```

Comment: Ah ok, `SynchronizationContext.Current == null ? TaskScheduler.Default : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` was what I was looking for. Thanks much.